# Hooks in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, hook

How can I call a hook for only a few controllers instead of all controllers in CodeIgniter?

E.g.: I want to run the hook for only the admin section. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can try to get the controller name in the hook, then only run the code when it's `admin`.  http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/62981/#778802

Answer (score 5):

In the hook which you wish to run selectively, you can access the ci superobject using `$this->ci =& get_instance();`. This acts as a pointer which can be used to access the CodeIgniter router to determine the class using `$class = $this->ci->router->fetch_class();`. You can then check if `$class` matches a certain value. This would give you:

```
<?php class Post_controller_constructor {
    var $ci;

    function __construct() {

    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $class = $this->ci->router->fetch_class();
        if($class === 'admin') {
            // Hook procedures
        }
    }
}

/* End of file post_controller_constructor.php */
/* Location: ./application/hooks/post_controller_constructor.php */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by checking url of your application in your hook:

```
$hook = false;
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"admin/"))
$hook = true;
if($hook) {
// do some hook stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will Enable Hooks in **`config/config.php`** File

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

Than Open `config/hooks.php` File

Than Define Hooks

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor']  = array(  
    'class'     => 'Post_controller_constructor',      // Class Name
   'function'  => 'check_status',     // Function Name
   'filename'  => 'Post_controller_constructor',   // File Name in Hook Folder
   'filepath'  => 'hooks'       // Controller Path
);
```

Than create hooks file in Hooks Folder Like `hooks/hooks.php`
open File

Here,
In the hook which you wish to run selectively, you can access the ci superobject using `$this->ci =& get_instance();`. This acts as a pointer which can be used to access the CodeIgniter router to determine the class using `$class = $this->ci->router->fetch_class()`;. You can then check if $class matches a certain value. This would give you:

```
<?php class Post_controller_constructor {
    var $ci;

    function __construct() {

    }

    function check_status()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $class = $this->ci->router->fetch_class();
        if($class === 'admin') {
            // Hook procedures
        }
    }
}

/* End of file post_controller_constructor.php */
/* Location: ./application/hooks/post_controller_constructor.php */
```