# In Codeigniter what is the purpose of hook ? Why we have to create?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

i am new to codeigniter. In Every interview all asked about hooks. i am not getting that what is hook why i have to use it ? what the benefit of it.

Comment: Check out this question of Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/q/23805693/3081659

Comment: Have you read this http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

Comment: i had read that but i am not getting the purpose of hook - syed Noman

Comment: Thank you for help

Comment: @HinaVaja Its simply like act like `_constructor` in function. `_constructor` will always call under every method used in that controller. In Hooks its load every time when controller initiated. Check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6-tPYHW374

Comment: Thank you - Spartan

Comment: hey, hooks is the thing which allows to alter the core functionality of the system without changing it physically. there are hooks like pre_sytem,post_system,pre_controller,post_controller,etc get executed as they are defined to be. and please do some practicals with below link given http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

Comment: Thanks - Kool-Mind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is example link  for use it hooks in codeigniter

https://qasimbadami.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/codeigniter-hooks-tutorial/

Note : suppose you have big project and almost 100 controller , if every time to check session exists or not , each and every post request 
so than to use hook

Answer (score 6):

Think in hooks as a middleware implementation in codeigniter.
Basically you can extend the basic functionallity of the framework adding code to specific moments of the request live cycle.

This is the lists of hooks available in codeigniter 2

> The following is a list of available hook points.
>
> **pre_system** Called very early during system execution. Only the
> benchmark and hooks class have been loaded at this point. No routing
> or other processes have happened.
>
> **pre_controller** Called immediately
> prior to any of your controllers being called. All base classes,
> routing, and security checks have been done.
>
> **post_controller_constructor** Called immediately after your controller
> is instantiated, but prior to any method calls happening.
>
> **post_controller** Called immediately after your controller is fully
> executed.
>
> **display_override** Overrides the _display() function, used to
> send the finalized page to the web browser at the end of system
> execution. This permits you to use your own display methodology. Note
> that you will need to reference the CI superobject with $this->CI =&
> get_instance() and then the finalized data will be available by
> calling $this->CI->output->get_output()
>
> **cache_override** Enables you to
> call your own function instead of the _display_cache() function in the
> output class. This permits you to use your own cache display
> mechanism.
>
> **post_system** Called after the final rendered page is sent to
> the browser, at the end of system execution after the finalized data
> is sent to the browser.