# What is hooks in codigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, hook

I want to know about hooks.Is is class or package or function or other?

> > Hooks is a concept?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html#hooks-extending-the-framework-core

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hooks in Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805693/hooks-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this url very help full to understand hooks in code-igniter http://www.javatpoint.com/codeigniter-hooks